# Cannot run docker in macbook white

Tags: macos, docker, virtualization

My macbook white processor is 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo.  4GB Memory. Macbook (13 inch, 2010).

I downloaded docker for mac and when I start it I get an error:

> Docker requires a processor with virtualization capabilities.

Please advise.  Is there a way to make docker work with my precious macbook white? Or should I buy a new one, will macbook pro run it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Docker 4 Mac requires Cpu with virtualization:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/
You may try Docker Toolbox, but I cannot guarantee, that it'll work:
https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/

As an alternative - try to install Ubuntu 32bit inside Virtualbox (it should be doable without VT) and then use docker inside this VM.

Unfortunately buying new computer is best solution ... 
Next thing is, that Mac isn't best OS to use Docker ... Docker for Mac has few drawbacks. I wrote article about some:
http://espeo.eu/blog/docker-for-mac-performance-tweaks/